# Testing Android in app billing

Tags: android, cordova, in-app-billing

I've developed an Android application that uses in app billing and I want to do some testing.

I've only one Andoid phone (my own). Therefore, when I try to do the testing, I can't buy the selled item (cause I'm the editor).
Is there an alternative way to do the testing?

Thanks

Comment: Do not forget to choose a answer if you are satisfied. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, you cannot do this testing without having a primary account with another, non developer console, email ID.

You will have to reset your device to factory settings and login with another account. There is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to buy/borrow a device specifically for testing which can still run a recent version of the Google Play client. It's the only way.